# How do I set the font size of the text on a swing jButton to the maximum size who fits the jButton

Tags: java, swing, font-size

I've got a jPanel with a jButton, and the user can define the size of the jPanel when launching the application using parameters, the jButton sizes according to the jPanel.

The problem is when I use a fixed font and the Panel is large, then the font looks very small, and vica versa.

So the font size should always be the maximum font size who fits in the button.

Comment: This seems like the basic problem when you let users specify the size of a JPanel or other container.  That is what Layouts are for.  If it is too big for the current view, throw it in a JScrollPane.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, but you might find the size using the Graphics.getFontMetrics() method inside the paintComponent-method? Maybe you can use the FontMetrics.getStringBounds() methods and test if the button contains that rectangle (RectangularShape.contains()).

You could use a binary search algorithm to find the max font.

Make sure you take the insets into account.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than messing with different font sizes.  I would suggest playing with the layout and keep the button from growing with the Panel size.  Allow the extra space to be taken up by other components in your panel.

Comment: My application is a 4x4 GridBagLayout who only contains buttons. It's a sort of numeric keypad for touch screen. So when the panel size is larger all the buttons should be enlarged including the text on the buttons. It's only a nice to have, but it's a very nice :-p

Comment: @stijn What about enlarging the space around the key pad after whatever point the buttons start to look bad.

Comment: I can also limit the maximum size, but thats not really what I want to do.